# .htaccess mod_rewrite that include query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some sample URLs I need rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blue-spares-cycle-for-cancer-research$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-item/?$ http://www.blue-group.com/en/news/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blue-spares-appoints-stuart-truckel-as-sales-director$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-item/?$ http://www.blue-group.com/en/news/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^project-manager-blue-machinery-london-ltd$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/careers/careers-item/$ http://www.blue-group.com/en/about/careers/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^000841:bakers-star-screen$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/screeners/used-machinery-item http://www.blue-group.com/en/used-machinery/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^000751:baler$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item http://www.blue-group.com/en/used-machinery/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My problem is I’ve got numerous similar URLs. Do I need to keep creating new `RewriteCond` for each one?

Also the results I’m getting are this for example:

```
http://www.blue-group.com/en/used-machinery/?000751:baler
```

Comment: If you are asking about consolidation (not just about `QSA`), then look into a `RewriteMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search turned up this:

Keep original query (default behavior)

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /target.php [L]
# from http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar
# to   http://example.com/target.php?foo=bar
```

Discard original query (notice the ? after target)

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /target.php? [L]
# from http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar
# to   http://example.com/target.php
```

Replace original query

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /target.php?bar=baz [L]
# from http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar
# to   http://example.com/target.php?bar=baz
```

Append new query to original query (QSA is key here)

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /target.php?bar=baz [QSA,L]
# from http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar
# to   http://example.com/target.php?foo=bar&bar=baz
```

Original from [here](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)